Case condition to filter and SUM in Oracle
In case stmt, I have a condition where I need to sum total values excluding below 3 scenarios

if column has NULL
Column has "AGING"
OR IF IT HAS EMPTY STRING

Attaching snippet for same.

But it is only excluding NULL values not "AGING" only when I am commenting NULL condition then it does exclude "AGING".
Please help what am I missing

Try not to post images of code.


Use AND not OR; and
Don't compare for equality/non-equality with '' as, in Oracle, '' is identical to NULL and will never be equal or not equal to anything else (including another NULL). Instead use IS NOT NULL (which means you can merge two of the checks).

SUM(
  CASE
  WHEN UPPER(acct.rule_cat_id) <> 'AGING'
  AND  TRIM(acc.rule_cat_id) IS NOT NULL
  THEN pcs_acct_dtl_ai.acct_cmpsn_amt
  ELSE 0
  END
)

As commented by @p3consulting, if you want to ignore all leading and trailing space in the comparison with AGING then you can simplify it further to:
SUM(
  CASE
  WHEN TRIM(UPPER(acct.rule_cat_id)) <> 'AGING'
  THEN pcs_acct_dtl_ai.acct_cmpsn_amt
  ELSE 0
  END
)

As anything where X <> 'AGING' is true then X is implicitly not NULL (since NULL <> anything will always be NULL and never true or false).

If we knew if ' AgInG ' should also NOT be returned then UPPER(TRIM(acct.rule_cat_cd)) <> 'AGING' could be enough.

@p3consulting I did consider that and didn't add initially it as it wasn't part of the logic described in the question; however, I've now included it in the answer based on your comment.
